# Exclude obfuscation of firebase imports using js-obfuscator webpack plugin

Tags: firebase, webpack, import, obfuscation

I would like to obfuscate my code but not Firebase import code using webpack and js-obfuscator plugin. Obfuscating Firebase code nearly doubles its size(more than 500kb)!

I tried many things like setting ignoreRequireImports to true. But that seems to work only with require imports and not tree shakable imports.

I also tried // javascript-obfuscator:disable comment around the import lines but that did not solved the problem either...

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

var WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');

module.exports = {
    mode:'production',
    devtool:'source-map',
    entry: { //'./src/firebaseConfig.js',
        //firebaseConfig:'./src/firebaseConfig.js',
        'scripts/signIn':'./src/signIn.js'
    },
    
    plugins:[
        new WebpackObfuscator({rotateStringArray: true, reservedStrings: [ '\s*' ]}, [])
    ],
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                enforce: 'post',
                use: {
                    loader: WebpackObfuscator.loader,
                    options: {
                        rotateStringArray: true,
                        reservedStrings: [ '\s*' ],
                        ignoreRequireImports:true
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output:{
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,'public'),
        filename:"[name].bundle.js"
        
    },   
    watch:true
}
```

Here is my source js file code:

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

```
import {
    getAuth 
}from 'firebase/auth';


import {
    getFirestore,
    collection,   
    getDocs    
} from 'firebase/firestore';

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore();
const auth=getAuth();

const colRef=collection(db,'books');

console.log(test);

getDocs(colRef).then((snapshot)=>{
    let books =[];
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc)=>{
        books.push({...doc.data(),id:doc.id})
    })
    console.log(books);
}).catch(err => {    
    
    console.log(err); 
})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add either a test condition tag (for specific files) or an exclude tag to limit the scope of the obfuscation task, see the following example:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            enforce: 'post',
            use: {
                loader: WebpackObfuscator.loader,
                options: {
                    rotateStringArray: true,
                }
            },
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
    ]
}
```